# Github Actions / Extract TicketID from branch name

Tags: regex, github, yaml, github-actions

You can currently set env vars via:

```
  - name: Configure Environment Variables
    uses: allenevans/set-env@v1.0.0
    with:
      CDN_PATH: app-foo/${{ github.run_id }}
      CDN_URL: 'https://cdn.mycompany.com'
      JIRA_TICKET_ID: ${{ match(github.ref, ...) }} # How can I extract a string from a branch name?
```

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#functions
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions

---

How can I extract a string from the branch name?

`JIRA_TICKET_ID: ${{ match(github.ref, ...) }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a build in function in github actions to do that. But you can run a step before your action that gets the jira ticket for you.

NOTE: You will need to modify the sed regex to the one to get your ticket. Right now it only gets the branch name from the ref

```
- id: getjiraticket
  run:  echo "::set-output name=jiraticketid::`echo "${{ github.ref }}" | sed 's/.*\///'`"
- name: Configure Environment Variables
  uses: allenevans/set-env@v1.0.0
  with:
    CDN_PATH: app-foo/${{ github.run_id }}
    CDN_URL: 'https://cdn.mycompany.com'
    JIRA_TICKET_ID: ${{ steps.getjiraticket.outputs.jiraticketid }}
```

Comment: thank you! I've been trying to achieve the syntax whole day and it is working beautifully!